# how to stop another function calling on window.open overrided function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which I called whenever a new tab opens from window.open as I have **overrode that function**. Also,

> I have attached a function on document.onclick event I need that
>   function to be a pause or stop whenever window.open function runs.

I know the **event.stopPropagation(); is used for achieving this** but in the function, it's not working as event argument couldn't pass.

```js
window.open = function(open) {
    return function(url) {
        console.log("url", url);
        
        // need to works here event.stopPropagation();
        return open.call(window, url);
    };
}(window.open);

document.onclick = clickListener;
function clickListener() {
  console.log("click");
};
function openLink(){
window.open('https://www.google.com')
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openLink()">open link</button>
```

Comment: Why would you need to override the native method though? Why not just put those custom window opener logic onto the `openLink` method?

Comment: because in reality, I wouldn't know which function will be called..so I need to call the function whenever new tab opened from a current page @jom

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this line? `...I need that function to be a pause or stop...`

Comment: Where and which event you want to stop?

Comment: means I don't wanna run that onclick function "clickListener" which will run on every click as you can see my snippet. I want to run that overrode function "window.open" to be run alone

Comment: You can try with window.event.stopPropagation() in overridden method of widnow.open.

Comment: @RakeshMakluri it worked!! tqsm :)

Comment: Updated the answer, please check once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event object will be available on window. You can try following:

```
    window.open = (function(open) {
    return function(url) {
        window.event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("url", url);

        // need to works here event.stopPropagation();
        return open.call(window, url);
    };
   })(window.open);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var staticVar = false;
window.open = function(open) {
    return function(url) {
        console.log("url", url);
        staticVar = true;
        // need to works here event.stopPropagation();
        return open.call(window, url);
    };
}(window.open);

document.onclick = clickListener;
function clickListener() {
 if(!staticVar) {
  console.log("click")
 }
 staticVar = false;
};
function openLink() {
    window.open('https://www.google.com');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openLink()">open link</button>
```

Comment: This is the one option like flag type